# How to create a fragment that does not cover the whole screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

Is it possible to create a fragment that opens from the side and comes to three-quarters of the screen? like navigateDrawer?
How to actually pull the fragment to a specific location on the screen that i first set

Answer (score 0):

You can use swapable tabhost refer following link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: I dont want any bars or tabs.

Comment: anyone know how to help me?\